# Remove hestia top bar

Tags: css, wordpress, navbar

I need to remove the navbar in my Hestia Theme.
I tried `.navbar  {display:none;}` and when I use it the top bar gets white and I need to remove it.

Could you help me with this problem, please?

Kind regards

[As it showed in the piture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWprg.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Wordpress sites the main tag has a margin at the top. This is causing the white bar above the page after you removed the navigation. You can "deactivate" this with:

```css
.main, main {
    margin-top: 0 !important;
}
```

**Edit:** I have checked out your site and have found the reason. There is some top padding defined by inline CSS at the article tag, that's get added by some JavaScript, but I cannot tell you why.

[image: inspector screenshot JS]

But you can still turn it of with:

```css
.elementor-page .pagebuilder-section {
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

This CSS rule is an extended rule already applied by Elementor, buts get overwritten by this inline CSS. I just added the `!important` to fix it:

[image: inspector screenshot CSS]

If that was helpful and you used this answer to solve your problem, it would be nice if you mark this answer as accepted. If this answer doesn't work or you have other questions, please response with a comment.

Comment: The top bar has been removed from the external pages but, the white color is still on the homepage.

Comment: @VICTORDANIELOMEROJAS Your problem is not reproducible from my point of view. Can you provide a link to the site?

Comment: Yeah¡
The web site is coasis.co

Comment: I updated my answer. TL;DR also use `.elementor-page .pagebuilder-section { padding: 0 !important; }`